# Как подключить внешний файл к расширению firefox?

Tags: javascript, браузер, расширения

Моя основная задача - сделать просто аналог расширения imacros для firefox.
В старых версия imacros была прекрасная возможность написания кода на JS с последующим его воспроизведением.

В связи с этим хочу написать расширение которое будет брать внешний файл (C:\ext\file.js)
и через команду eval() воспроизводить код из внешнего файла.

Подскажите рабочий пример.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Если хочется написать свой плагин, изучайте
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension

Comment: А как ваше сообщение отвечает на вопрос ТС? Честно говоря, не вижу взаимосвязи.